# ngOnChanges is not triggered when value changes from select

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngonchanges

I have next html:

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="district"  class="form-control" (change)="dsChange()">

      <option disabled hidden [value]="undefined" >Ноҳия</option>

      <option *ngFor="let dis of districts" [ngValue]="dis">{{dis.title}}</option>
</select>
```

Also I have next component

```
@Input() district: District;
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      console.log("CHANGED")
}
 dsChange(){
      console.log(this.district);
}
```

And I can not understand why when I select some value dsChange is triggered with correct value of district, but ngOnChanges() not

Comment: why close voiting? can someone explain plz

Comment: This has to do with interaction between components, which is where @ Input and @ Output are used and is covered here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ngOnChanges` is called when a component's data-bound input properties change. In your case, it would be called if the parent component sets a new value for `@Input() district`.

[See the docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence)

> #### ngOnChanges()
>
> Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties...Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.

Answer (score 1):

It's not calling the `onChanges` even though the variable is local to the component.I created a plukr for this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/lsqyeZ8aiBpylciOQxnU?p=preview